# Open .sqlite files from terminal Mac

Tags: sqlite

I have to do a project with a SQL database. I am asked to use the following file:

> https://github.com/jpwhite3/northwind-SQLite3/blob/master/Northwind_small.sqlite

But the file downloads as .sqlite and I can't open it from my terminal. It is part of the requirement to only open it from the terminal, I can't use SQLite studio or anything like that as I should be able to open it directly. When I try to open it I get the following error:

> Error: near line 1: near "SQLite": syntax error

or got an empty database, but when I open it with SQLite studio, all the data is in the file.

This is a screenshot from my terminal:

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42JW2.png)

---

---

I need to download the data base and be able to manage it.

Comment: Try `sqlite3 Northwind_small.sqlite` i.e. using a capital `N`.

Comment: Or try `sqlite> .open Documents/sqlite....`